# How to add a shortcut to a NFS share in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, nfs

I have defined a NFS mount point in Disk Utility. The target machine is running Linux.
I don't see the machine in Finder (preferences/ shared / servers is checked)
I also can't drag the folder to the Finders Favorites.

All of this is possible if I mount the NFS share manually through the command line.

Is there a setting to have the NFS mount points behave like the other folders on my system (OS X 10.7.3) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Finder, go to preferences, then click Sidebar. Under the Shared group, tick Connected Servers.